# Extracting the name of the author from an Amazon page using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to use beautifulSoup to extract information from an html file.

```
<a href="/s?_encoding=UTF8&amp;field-author=Reza%20Aslan&amp;search-alias=books&amp;sort=relevancerank">Reza Aslan</a> <span class="byLinePipe">(Author)</span>
```

I'm using the beautiful soup findAll function to extract the author, Reza Azlan from the previous code with this

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re


ecj_data = open("book1.html",'r').read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(ecj_data)

for definition in soup.findAll('span', {"class":'byLinePipe'}):
    definition = definition.renderContents()
```

The `print definition` command gives me : "Release date:"

Which means that there is another class with "byLiniePipe"

```
<div class="buying"><span class="byLinePipe">Release date: </span><span style="font-weight: bold;">July 16, 2013</span> </div>
```

Does anybody know how I can differentiate between these sets of code to get the Authors name to print out?

Comment: Can you post the URL or the entire HTML instead of snippets?

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/Zealot-Times-Jesus-Nazareth-ebook/dp/B00BRUQ7ZY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to find a unique marker near the author's name instead of going through the collection of elements with like classes. For example, we can locate the title of the book using its unique `id` then we locate the very next link to it (which contains the author's name) using the `find_next` function. See code below.

**Code:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bsoup
import requests as rq

url = "http://www.amazon.com/Zealot-Times-Jesus-Nazareth-ebook/dp/B00BRUQ7ZY"
r = rq.get(url)
soup = bsoup(r.content)

title = soup.find("span", id="btAsinTitle")
author = title.find_next("a", href=True)

print title.get_text()
print author.get_text()
```

**Result:**

```
Zealot: The Life and Times of Jesus of Nazareth [Kindle Edition]
Reza Aslan
[Finished in 2.4s]
```

Hope this helps.